# Keeping the zeroes when converting varchar to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to keep the preceding zeros when converting varchar to float
in SQL Server Select query ?

```
declare @data varchar(100) = '000.1234';
```

when we convert @data to float, it will get 0.1234 only.

But how to keep the full zeroes after converting from varchar to float like 000.1234 [ie, without trimming any zeroes]

sometimes `@data may be '00.23'`

even though, it has to keep what ever be the preceding zeroes after conversion.

Comment: Keep it as `varchar`?

Comment: What significance do the leading zeros have? Why do you want to preserve them? `000.1234` and `0.1234` are exactly the same number.

Comment: Hi, I want the float datatype after select query. That's why converting varchar to float.

Comment: Keeping the number of preceding zeros, is a business logic so i cant change that.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers are always stored physically in a format that does not preserve leading zeroes (as they do not affect the actual value being stored).

So keep the value in a varchar to preserve the formatting, or have a separate field that stores how many extra leading zeroes you need when formatting the number.